# Change the Default geodatabase in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, default

In a multi-user environment I have a need to be able to configure ArcGIS so that it uses an SDE connection as the default geodatabase instead of the Default.gdb in each users' profile.  What is the best way to do this?  An add-in?

Answer (score 8):

Setting the Default GeoDatabase is super easy. Follow this link here to see the ESRI tutorial on this: [Setting the default geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sn0000000t000000.htm). You can set this to an SDE connection as well if that is an issue. Create a base MXD with the SDE as the default GeoDatabase. Create a shortcut for it and instead of having your users open ArcMap with the normal ArcMap exe, have them always launch ArcMap with this MXD.